# Accessing ArrayCollection inside an Entity with findBy

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to fetch an object from the Database with findOneBy, but the identifier of an object that differentiates individual objects is inside an ArrayCollection member of this class. ( not counting id )

The relation is OneToMany Unidirectional, which makes it ManyToMany with JoinTable, now I know how to find an object with its "single variable" members, like so:

```
$em->getRepository('ExampleEntity')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'example');
```

Does anyone know how to access the ArrayCollection variable member with the same method, that is using find*, or maybe DQL ? CustomRepository ?

Thank You.

P.S. I am deeply sorry, if there already exists a question like this, I have searched.

EDIT:

I should probably also say, that the ArrayCollection is an Entity in itself, and it contains two fields, name and data ( I know, vague, that is because the Entity itself is vague )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to find by field that it is arrayCollection field in the entity. The following query should works:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('ExampleEntity')->createQueryBuilder('alias');

return $queryBuilder
   ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('alias.arrayField', 'value'))
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but unfortunately, that does not work, or at least I do not know how to make it work, if I substitute 'value' for an actual object, it throws an exception saying that __toString should never throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Using benatespina's answer and this answer [findBy with JOIN criteria in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257911/findby-with-join-criteria-in-symfony2?rq=1) I have found an answer.

You can 'go' into any array inside an Entity, by using DQL with its joins, i.e.

```
$builder = $entityManager->getRepository('ExampleRepo')->createQueryBuilder(<alias_0>);
$query = $builder
            ->join('<alias_0>.<name_of_your_array_of_entities>', '<alias_1>')
            ->join('<alias_1>.<another_array>', '<alias_2>')
            ->join('<alias_2>.<yet_another_array>', '<alias_3>')
            ->where('<alias_3>.<name_of_your_variable> = :placeholder')
            ->setParameters(array('placeholder' => <variable_value>))
            ->getQuery();
```

Bare in mind, that this might be performing very poorly, to be honest, I have no idea how it performs, so please test it yourself.

In case You have inheritance in your structure, DQL will not be that helpful, what you need to do, is get an actual object You want to check against, use the method I have just shown You, get to the lowest possible array you can, and check against the ID of that actual object You got earlier.

Like so:

```
$object = $entityManager->getRepository('SomeObjectDeepInYourStructure')->findOneBy(array(<criteria>));
$entityManager->getRepository('ExampleRepo')->createQueryBuilder(<alias_0>);
$query = $builder
            ->join('<alias_0>.<lowest_array>', '<alias_1>')
            ->where('<alias_1>.id = :id')
            ->setParameters(array('id' => $object->getId()))
            ->getQuery();
```

This obviously makes sense only in a scenario, in which You have a Unidirectional relation. Hope it helps anyone with similar problem.